# jQueryUI FullCalendar: Callback after events have been fetched from server

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I use the jQueryUI FullCalendar from Adam Shaw (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/).

When I press the next button the calendar loads new events from my server and I would like to show these events also as a table on my page, not only in the calendar. Is there a callback function that I can inject to do something with the events, once FullCalendar has fetched them? Or is there any other way to get the currently shown events?

Comment: I have done something similar with my calendar, were i had to interact with fullcalendar events both in calendar and outside calendar through a datatable.

Try to use Datatables jquery plugin it will make your life easy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by actually rewriting the code to fetch the data:

```
var myCustomFunction = function(events) {
    // do something
}

var myCustomFetchFunction = function(start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'feed.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
            start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
            end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
            // additional parameters can be added here
        },
        success: function(events) {
            callback(events);
            // this is where I do some custom stuff with the events
            myCustomFunction(events);
        }
    });
};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     events: myCustomFetchFunction()
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I explained in my first answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just could not understand your answer, I guess more code would have helped. But maybe it is just me. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 3):

For others seeking out this solution, it's pretty easy in V2. You can pass a success callback using the simple events object.

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: {
                url: 'http://yourdatafeed',
                type: 'POST',
                error: function() {
                    // Alert on error
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // data will have your json array of event objects
                },
            }
        });
```

Comment: Any solutions for v5? Unknown option 'success' in console

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted shows the answer to your question:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: function(start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
...
```

The "events" callback function is used every time new events are fetched. In the example the `$.ajax` function of jQuery is called to retrieve the events data (have a look at [the ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). The "success" callback of `$.ajax` then parses the event data from the server into the format that FullCalendar expects:

```
$(doc).find('event').each(function() {
     events.push({
         title: $(this).attr('title'),
         start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
     });
 });
callback(events);
```

In the example 'doc' is an xml document which contains event elements with a title and a start attribute. You should change this to whatever you retrieve from the server. With the data retrieved you can do anything you want before or after you pass it to FullCalendar (with `callback(events);` as in the example)

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the function to fetch the events. I rather want to add a callback that gets called after FullCalendar has fetched the events successfully. Could you please guide me further here.

Comment: You should take a look at [this page](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/). There is an event `eventAfterAllRender` that might be helpful. Or `eventRender` which passes the event.

Comment: How would I get the events inside the eventAfterAllRender Callback Function?
The ViewObject does not hold the events: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Object/

Comment: What do you want to do with the events exactly? Do you need the complete set of events or do you want to do something with each event individually?

Comment: I want all events and inject them as dom elements into my website. So I basically want to get title and date from all events and create html out of them.

Comment: I posted another answer since this one is not what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess it would helped me a lot if you would have guided me towards the point, that I just need to add my custom code after the line "callback(events)" once I reimplement the fetching code.

Answer (score 0):

Use eventRender to insert the events in your DOM. See [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    // do some DOM manipulation here
}
```

Or collect them to insert them into the DOM later:

```
var collection = [];
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        collection.push(event);
    }
});
```